# Bounty Message despite Accepted Answer

Tags: discussion, bug, bounty, user-interface

[image: Bounty1]

Why am I getting this message? (Note in this case I'm getting it **after** accepting an answer.)

[image: Bounty]

In this case, I had this message for long as I had neither accepted nor received any answer. But then, after sometime I answered and accepted the answer but still the message is there.

The screenshots are from the "Questions" tab in "Profile" menu.

Why do these messages still show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon careful observation, you'll uncover something different.

Kindly note that **you have**:
[image: bounty screen]

And so **technically the screenshot should be**:
[image: Bounty screen 2]

Similarly, **in the following case**:
[image: bounty 3]

The **correct screenshot should have been**:
[image: bounty 4]

This turns the situation upside down. The message was never meant for the questions that you thought it belonged to but for the question just below them.

Luckily the questions below them still don't have an accepted solution so it wasn't hard to crack. Though for the last screenshot above, the bounty message has now (most likely) moved over to a relatively newer question (as per some algorithm).

Comment: Are you talking to yourself?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Haha. I wrote a general answer so that when anyone reads it looks that way.

Comment: I do it too, both just like this in answers to my questions, and out loud. +1